# Convert font "Cambria Math" to plain text with js

Tags: javascript, math, text, ms-word, notepad

I have a text "", the problem is that when i get this text it doesn't change, it stays in font format "Cambria Math". Notepad doesn't help translate this. The font can be seen in Microsoft Word. Is it possible to translate this into plain text "TBL" using javascript?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the normalize() method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize
Example js:

```
var name1 = '';
var name2 = 'TBL';
var name1NF = name1.normalize('NFC').normalize('NFKC').normalize('NFD').normalize('NFKD')
if(name1NF==name2){
    alert("good");
}
```